# Transparent elements on solid background

Tags: c#, background, transparency

I've spotted a little issue. When I am setting some objects fore color to transparent it shows what is on desktop, not below them.

Do you know any possible way around?

Thanks a lot,
Michael

Comment: Possibly way around might be the WPF.

Comment: What is WPF? Windows Presentation Foundation? Unfortunetly unavailable.

Comment: That's not the way it works, you'd have to set the TransparencyKey first and make the BackColor or ForeColor match that value.  Yes, that punctures a hole through the entire window, you see what's behind the window.  Feature, not a bug.

Comment: Ye, but some way around? I've got ProgBar with ForeColor transparent and image below. I want to see image appears when it performs step. But instead I see desktop. :/